# Web socket Ping/Pong and Close control frames implementation

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, rfc6455

This is my first time to write socket programs and I don't how to implement websocket ping/pong and close control frames in RFC 6455 in C# ( without any third party libraries, I want to implement manually ). Is there someone who has implemented already these control frames in C# or any other programing languages? Please give any sample solutions or correct direction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at [WebSocket4Net](https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net)

Comment: I have used the Fleck library, you could check their source:
https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck

Comment: There's a ruby implementation in [the Plezi Framework's source code](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/eca79456f34c2129a255a117a27a7eb63380eddc/lib/plezi/server/websocket.rb#L161-L189).

Comment: Hi, I develop WebSocketListener that uses ping/pong: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener It is developed in C#

Answer (score 1):

Close frames have an op code of 8. You can answer it with a close frame (it will be ignored), but then disconnect.

Pings have an op code of 9. You need to answer any ping with a pong.

Pongs have an op code of 10. Pongs don't need to be answered.

To answer a Ping, the Pong should contain the body of the message sent with the Ping.

Remember a Ping and a Pong can be sent in the middle of a multi-framed message!

You can find a Ruby implementation within [The Plezi Framework's Websocket Protocol source code](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/2ad3727f19cc48f264bf776f27e292c22553665b/lib/plezi/server/websocket.rb#L161-L189).

I'm sure there are C# implementations as well. @ThomasLevesque suggested [WebSocket4Net](https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net)... maybe that would fit what you're searching for a bit better.

Good Luck!